# Rails - self referential association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations

I'm creating RoR app. I have a model named 'User'. I want to create a 'Many to many' relationship between Users. It's then self referential association.

I generated 'Friendship' model with corresponding controller:
rails g model Friendship friend1:integer, friend2:integer, active:boolean
rails g controller Friendships create destroy

After clicking on 'Add friend',  friendship_controller is called with 'create' action. This action should create new 'Friendship', but when I click on 'Add friend', mistake appears: unknown attribute 'user_id' for Friendship.

Here is code that I wrote:

VIEW: (@user is a guy who I want to add as friend)

```
<%= link_to 'Add friend', create_friendship_path(:friend2 => @user), :method => :post %>
```

ROUTES:

```
post 'create_friendship' => 'friendships#create'
```

CONTROLLER:

```
class FriendshipsController < ApplicationController
  def create
    @friendship = current_user.friendships.build(:friend2 => params[:friend2])
    if @friendship.save
      flash[:notice] = 'Friend added'
    else
      flash[:error] = 'Friend was not added'
    end
  end
end
```

USER MODEL:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :friendships
  has_many :friends, through: :friendships
end
```

FRIENDSHIP MODEL:

```
class Friendship < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :friend, class_name: 'User'
  validates :friend1, presence: true
  validates :friend2, presence: true
end
```

I have never used self referential associations with Rails, so there is a mistake which I can't find. Thanks for advices.

Schema.rb

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20150904134846) do

  create_table "friendships", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer  "friend1"
    t.integer  "friend2"
    t.boolean  "accepted"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

  add_index "friendships", ["friend1", "friend2"], name: "index_friendships_on_friend1_and_friend2", unique: true
  add_index "friendships", ["friend1"], name: "index_friendships_on_friend1"
  add_index "friendships", ["friend2"], name: "index_friendships_on_friend2"

  create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.string   "email"
    t.boolean  "admin",           default: false
    t.string   "password_digest"
    t.string   "remember_digest"
    t.datetime "created_at",                      null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                      null: false
  end

  add_index "users", ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email"

end
```

Comment: Post your schema.rb file.

Comment: I edited my post with Schema. rb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your schema for the `friendships` table doesn't follow the Rails standards for defining a belong association, therefore the code is crashing.

Specifically, you defined the associations with

```
t.integer  "friend1"
t.integer  "friend2"
```

whereas Rails by default expects a field named after the association plus `_id`.

```
belongs_to :user
belongs_to :friend, class_name: 'User'
```

Therefore you should have used

```
t.integer  "user_id"
t.integer  "friend_id"
```

Either rename the fields in the database or use the `foreign_key` option to override the defaults.